# Reprojecting coordinates using MakePoint() with SpatiaLite?

Tags: coordinate-system, sql, coordinates, spatialite

In my SpataLite-DB, I've got a table holding coordinates in EPSG:2056, splitted in two columns "x_coord" and "y_coord".

I want to copy them into another table, using MakePoint to convert the two coordinate columns into a geometry (EPSG:21781) column.

Is it possible to convert the coordinates during the copy process, or do I have to first convert and then copy  them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to set the coordinate system in the makepoint function and then transform it using transform.

The following would return a geometry in EPSG:21781

```
select transform(makepoint(x_coord,y_coord, 2056),21781)
```